# mule DataMapper vs groovy or similar

Tags: mule

Is there any best practice on when to use Datamapper vs Groovy transformers etc when performing transformations or mappings in Mule?

For example I need to transform xml to json etc. I can do this nicely with Groovy using the XML builders and Json builders and its open source etc. It requires me to write some code though.

Where as Datamapper is EE only and seems a lot more opaque being a visual drag and drop.

Are there any downsides to not using DataMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said data mapper is a graphical building tool. As pros:

1. Easier to maintain
2. User don't need any special programing skill
3. Support for data sense in studio

But as you said there is nothing that you can not do either with groovy or a java component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Datamapper are for enterprise edition, but there are following advantages :-
1. Extraction and loading of flat and structured data formats
2. Filtering, extraction and transformation of input data using XPath and powerful scripting
3. Augmenting data with input parameters and lookups from other data sources
Live design-time previews of transformation results
4. It definitely has high-performance, scalable data mapping operations

Full reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference
Only issue I see in Datamapper is you need to maintain the mapping files.

But for the community edition user, they need to find other options in transforming and mapping .
In that case as you said, they might use their custom Java classes, Groovy component, expression component etc.